# Constant current Opamp circuit issues

Tags: current, operational-amplifier, driver

I have implemented a constant current source for an high power LED. I am using the following topology.
[image]

I have the following problems:

- Even a small noise on IN+ causes some current to pass through Rsense and make the LED turn on, although it is very weak, it consumes power and not ideal. How can I make this work only above certain voltage on IN+, for example 1V.
- I couldn't push the current through LED to very high numbers. I use a 5A capable BJT and MCP6021 as opamp. I can see up to 1.5A but cannot get pass that. (1.5A measured on Rsense's voltage drop). The capacitors are 4x 420uF Electrolytic. (I didn't have a 1mF handy so I put in 4 parallel caps) Do I need a special cap?

Comment: What part number is Q1?

Comment: @NickAlexeev 2N5191 from ST Micro http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00001220.pdf or something very close to this.. I am not in the office.

Comment: That looks familiar !

Comment: @Rocketmagnet it is your proposal, I am just trying build it. After building the darlington pair, I am still not able to achieve 5A (Based on the voltage reading on Rsense) with 1ohm, but if I put 0.5ohm, I see close to 5A. The problem is the LED, it is not behaving as it should. The output flux has not increased according to the datasheet. (I put a Photodetector receiver to measure relative light output and it didn't 5x from 1A to 5A but it should according to datasheet) Need to debug further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a wonder you get 1.5A at all.

*edit*
*Since you mention 3.3V as the input for your boost regulator I'll presume that this is also the power supply for your 555 and opamp. The LM555 doesn't work at this low voltage, so you'll have to use the CMOS version, [TLC555](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf).*

\$H_{FE}\$ for the 2N5191 at 1.5A is minimum 25, so you'll need 60mA of base current. An \$H_{FE}\$ of 25 makes that the opamp sees the 0.5\$\Omega\$ emitter resistor as 12.5\$\Omega\$. That's still low, so it won't be the limiting factor for the base current: \$\dfrac{3.3V - 0.7V}{12.5\Omega}\$ = 208mA.

The problem is the opamp. At 2.5V power supply the MCP6021's short circuit current is typically 30mA, which in a worst case situation will only give you 750mA collector current. The reason you *do* get 1.5A is that the 25 is the transistor's minimum \$H_{FE}\$, it can go up to 100.

The \$H_{FE}\$ you get is typical for a power transistor, so swapping it for another type probably won't help much. You can use a Darlington, or make your own by adding a small signal transistor to drive the power transistor's base. The [BC817](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BC817_BC817W_BC337.pdf) will be suitable.

A MOSFET is also a possibility, but this should be chosen with care. Even logic MOSFETs don't always give their maximum current at 5V \$V_{GS}\$, and the sense resistor subtracts also a certain voltage from it. The 555's output divider gives 1.65V for the opamp's non-inverting input, and given enough drive current the sense resistor will also settle to 1.65V, giving 3.3A to the LEDs. That means that the MOSFET should be able to give 3.3A of drain current at only 3.3V - 1.65V = 1.65V \$V_{GS}\$. That's very low! But by a lucky coincidence an answer to another recent question showed this graph:

[image]

That damned [AO6408](http://aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO6408.pdf) delivers 8A at only 1.5V \$V_{GS}\$! Tailor-made for the job!

Comment: *Even logic MOSFETs don't always give their maximum current at 5V \$V_{GS}\$* - As long as the gate insulation can handle it (\$V_{GS} < BV_{GSO}\$, the Gate-Source Breakdown Voltage), increasing \$V_{GS}\$ will always increase the carrier concentration in the channel when the FET is in saturation mode.   The more important factor for logic-level MOSFETs is the threshold voltage \$V_{th}\$.

Comment: \$V_{GS}\$ is typically fixed at 3.3V or 5V, so you need to focus on \$V_{th}\$.  The ratio between \$V_{GS}\$ and \$I_D\$ is \$(V_{GS}-V_{th})^2\$ - Note the quadratic!  Observe the huge jump in your graph from 8A to 32A between  \$V_{GS}=1.5V\$ and  \$V_{GS}=2V\$; this graph must be crafted for the maximum threshold voltage of the AO6408, which is one volt.  The relation checks out: \$8A*(2V-1V)^2/(1.5V-1V)^2\ = 32V\$

Comment: You seem astonished that the AO6408 can do this, but for more high-\$I_D\$ at low \$V_{GS}\$ parts, go into FETs-single at Digikey and look for N-channel MOSFETs with a logic-level feature having a `Vgs(th) (Max) @ Id` of 1 volt or less.   There are over 200 options in cut-tape and tube packaging. (Did I mention I love Digikey?) For example, consider this graph from the [STL100N1VH5 datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/DM00024138.pdf): http://i.stack.imgur.com/rsCIf.png shows over 200 Amps at 3.3V!

Comment: Also, there's no reason the gate voltage is limited to 3.3 V --- OP hasn't said what's the op-amp power supply voltage.

Comment: @Kevin - I don't have much experience with logic level MOSFETs, but I have seen quite a few which had an \$I_D\$ of hundreds of mA at 3V or 5V, while they needed a \$V_{GS}\$ of 10V or higher to get the rated 5A or so.

Comment: @ThePhoton - In my introductory edit I presumed he used the same 3.3V as he used for the boost regulator. Anyway he can't use the 12V, the MCP6021 is a 5V device.

Comment: OK. I see it now.

Answer (score 3):

> - Even a small noise on IN+ causes some current to pass through Rsense and make the LED turn on, although it is very weak, it consumes power and not ideal. How can I make this work only above certain voltage on IN+, for example 1V.

Simply take your feedback from the output of the op-amp (the base of the BJT). Now if the input signal is less than about 0.6 V, no IR output.

If you still want to have the same maximum output you can adjust the two resistors (not labelled in your schematic) to increase the "on" voltage input to the op-amp by 0.7 V or so.

**EDIT**

As Nick Alexeev points out the above is a bit of a "quick-and-dirty" solution. It gives about 100-200 mA of uncertainty of the output current. It might also restrict your options with solving the issue of the op-amp not having enough "oomph" to provide the base current in the BJT that you need to get the output current you want (as detailed in Nick's answer).

Here's a solution that solves both problems (this replaces the op-amp, BJT, and sense resistor in your circuit):

[image]

With this circuit you don't need to worry about the drive capability of the op-amp. You also reduce the output current uncertainty. The original circuit had possible errors due to the resistor variation (0.5 - 5%, depending what resistor you buy) and the BJT beta (1 - 2%).

With this you are left with just the resistor variation and an error due to the variation in the diode forward voltage.

If the 47 kOhm resistor makes this circuit respond too slowly for your needs, you may need to reduce the values of your voltage divider resistors to enable you to reduce the value of the new resistor.

**EDIT 2**

To reduce component count, you could build the diode in to your resistor divider. R1 here replaces the lower resistor in the divider. The value of R1 would be reduced to 10 kOhms. An additional resistor is added in series with the diode to be the upper resistor in the divider.  The input then comes straight from the 555.

The value of the upper resistor should be chosen to give the output current you want when the input is high.

Comment: Are you suggesting to connect the inverting input of the OpAmp (-) to the output of the OpAmp?  If so, you should get a voltage follower.  That would defeat the constant current function.  (May be I didn't understand your suggestion correctly.)

Comment: Yes. Q1 and RSense will still make this a current source. Maybe not as stiff as the original, but probably okay.

Comment: @ThePhoton beats the purpose. I need a stable constant current source.

Comment: Thinking it over, it will be a high impedance current source, but will have some uncertainty about the output current (due to not knowing the BJT's Vbe accurately). See edits for an alternative.

Comment: If you use a diode as a reference for the voltage divider, it makes the op-amp largely pointless. You can easily make the output of a 555 turn on an NPN-based constant current source, without any intervening op-amp.

Answer (score 1):

> - I couldn't push the current through LED to very high numbers. I use a
>     5A capable BJT and MCP6021 as opamp. I can see up to 1.5A but cannot
>     get pass that. (1.5A measured on Rsense's voltage drop).

The max output current of MCP6021 is 30mA, which is the <s>gate</s> base current \$I_b\$.  The LED current is the collector current \$I_c=I_b h_{FE}\$. We don't know what model Q1 is, but the values of \$h_{FE}\$ (sometimes it's also called beta) are usually between 10 and few hundred.  It agrees with 1.5A max, which you're getting. A [Darlington pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_pair) or a MOSFET could give you more current.

Comment: Now this somewhat make sense... However, wouldn't the transistor go into saturation if the pull of current is large? If I switch to mostfet, what type of Mosfet I should choose?

Comment: This solves the second problem, how about the first one?